# s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration not a valid permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, boto3

[This documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-bucket-subresources) that specifies the permission for s3 bucket subresources states that `s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration` and `s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration` are the permissions for giving access to the GET Bucket encryption operation.  But when I apply these permissions in a policy, the policy editor informs me the actions are not recognized.

Furthermore, when I save the policy with these permissions, and apply the policy to a lambda function (or IAM user), the GET Bucket encryption operation operation fails.  Used from boto3 in python, for example:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: Access Denied
```

When all s3 permissions or all Get permissions are applied (`s3:*` or `s3:Get*`), the operation succeeds.  But when I check every single box for s3 actions in the policy editor to explicitly include each permission, the operation still fails with access denied.

**What is the correct name for this action?**  I've tried simply `GetBucketEncryption`, but still no dice.  There is clearly SOMETHING that gives permission for the operation or the wildcard actions wouldn't work.

Does not work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Works:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration` should be correct.  The policy editor does seem to have some bugs since the recent enhancements.  If I were to guess which other permission you might need beyond that, depending on exactly how you're crafting the request, it could be `s3:GetBucketLocation`.

Comment: You're right that the new, visual policy editor does not know this permission. However, I just tried it with `aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket=BUCKET_NAME`. 

Without `s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration`, I got `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: Access Denied`

With, I got `An error occurred (ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: The server side encryption configuration was not found`, i.e. not permission related.

Comment: I hit this issue when running `terraform refresh` on a created S3 bucket. Adding the `s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration` in the Visual Editor reports a warning now ("Unrecognized actions") but the new policy version can be saved and actually grants the permission correctly. Lucky that the Visual Editor allows saving with a warning.